# NLog - Archive Start / Stop Time

Tags: c#, .net, logging, nlog

Just started working with NLog and have it running with the following configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  throwConfigExceptions="true">

  <targets async="true">
    <target name="logfile"
        xsi:type="File"
        layout="${longdate} [${level:uppercase=true}] (${threadid}) ${logger}: ${message} ${onexception:${newline}Exception\: ${exception:format=type,message,method,stacktrace:maxInnerExceptionLevel=5:innerFormat=shortType,message,method}}"
        fileName="logs/current.log"
        archiveFileName="logs/Archive/${ticks}.log"
        archiveEvery="Minute"
        archiveOldFileOnStartup="true"
        keepFileOpen="false"
    />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="logfile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Everything is working as expected. However, I need to have the rotated file be in the format of `${archive_start_ticks}_${arhive_end_ticks}.log` rather than the current format which is `${archive_end_ticks}.log`.

I was initially hoping I could name the active log file as ${ticks} and then, on archive, use the active log file's name as a parameter into the archive file to compose some like:

```
 fileName="logs/${ticks}"
 archiveFileName="logs/Archive/${fileName}_${ticks}.log"
```

Of course, there's two issues here:

1. Using ${ticks} for the active file creates a new file for each log line.
2. I can't seem to reference the original fileName as an input variable into archiveFileName.

That said, what is the best way to achieve this goal? Is this something NLog can handle natively or with minor extensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating in case anyone ever cares:

I bailed on using the FileTarget with configurations and wrote my own Target wrapped in a BufferedWrapper. On each flush, I use the first and last LogEvents to determine the timespan which gives me what I need to for the required file format with little custom code to support.